# how to solve this in code problem code forces

Tags: c++

You are given 2 chess Knights positions.

Your task is easy, just find if one knight can attack the other one in one or less moves.

Input
The first line contains 2 space-separated integers x1,y1 the position of the first knight.

The next line contains the second knight position x2,y2. Where (1 ≤ x1, y1, x2, y2 ≤ 100)

Output
Print "Yes" if one of the knights can attack the other one, print "No" otherwise.

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: People will be able to help solve specific problems *with your code*. Please upload a minimum, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Here's the algorithm.

```
For all possible destinations for the first knight:
  If the destination is the same position as the second knight:  
      print "Yes"
      End.
```

I recommend looking up chess rules for moving a knight.  Not all destinations will lie within the bounds of the chess board.

**Edit 1:  Table of Knight Moves**
One implementation is to have a table of possible knight moves:

```
struct Offset
{
  int x_offset;
  int y_offset;
};

const std::Offset  knight_offsets[] =
{
  {1, 2}, // one over, two down
  {1, -2}, // one over, two up
  //...
};
const unsigned int MAX_KNIGHT_OFFSETS =
  sizeof(knight_offsets) / sizeof(knight_offsets[0]);  

// ...
bool killed = false;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_KNIGHT_OFFSETS; ++i)
{
   if ((x1 + knight_offsets[i].x_offset) == x2)  
       && (y1 + knight_offsets[i].y_offset) == y2))
   {
       break;
   }
}
if (i < MAX_KNIGHT_OFFSETS)
{
  std::cout << "Yes\n";
}
else
{
  std::cout << "No\n";
}
```

The algorithm adds the offset to Knight 1's position, then checks if the position is the same as Knight 2.  If they are the same, then Knight 2 can be killed.
Otherwise the next move is checked.

Answer (score 1):

First, one need to know how the knight moves in chess. It moves in "L" shape and it ignores pieces in its path. This behavior is better described, for instance, in [Wikipedia - Knight (chess)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_(chess))

Hence, if the knight is in the position (x1,y1), it can only move to the following 8 spaces:

- (x1 - 2, y1 - 1)
- (x1 - 2, y1 + 1)
- (x1 - 1, y1 - 2)
- (x1 - 1, y1 + 2)
- (x1 + 1, y1 - 2)
- (x1 + 1, y1 + 2)
- (x1 + 2, y1 - 1)
- (x1 + 2, y1 + 1)

As long as the second knight is in one of those positions, it can be eaten in one or less moves.

Also, if we assume the input (x1, y1, x2, y2) is only made of valid positions (which is usually the case of Code Force problems), we do not need to check if those positions are valid or not. This is so because we will only get a YES if we have a match of the tested position and the knight position, which we know is valid.

Hence, your code should be something like this:

```
canEat = false;

FOR: each one of the (x,y) positions listed above)
   IF: x2 == x && y2 == y
      canEat = true;

PRINT: canEat ? "YES" : "NO);
```